# Are large currents from my motor killing my Arduino?

Tags: arduino, power, current

In my last question about the circuit below, it was mentioned that the motors can emit large amounts of current at peaks. I am worried that this large amount of current may be the reason I keep breaking Arduinos.

Are the large swaths of current causing my Arduino to break? If so, how can I fix it? If not what else is likely causing my Arduino to break?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr7pRP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

Comment: What is the current of the motor ?

Comment: This 4:28 minute video https://youtu.be/avrdDZD7qEQ seems to be similar to your application and does not seem to harm the Arduino.

Comment: @StefanMerfu I do not know, it is 28BYJ-48 stepper motor and not much is clear about it. Physically it is very small

Comment: @SystemTheory Thank you, however I have seen this video before, and copying the wiring I can get the motor to turn, however, I don't have the ability to control its direction and the torque is very small. I got one working a while ago with good torque and direction but I cannot seem to get it to work again without an arduino failing

Comment: Is the thing you've marked "ULN2003" really a motor driver board that happens to contain a ULN2003, among other stuff, rather than a simple ULN2003 IC?

Comment: @PeterBennett Yes it is, my mistake, I am not very good at schematics

Comment: See all those wires? They have resistance. You get a voltage drop when current passes through them. Also remember current flows in a loop. Draw out your current loops. Make sure your 12V current loop doesn’t flow through the 5av current loop. According to your photo, the 0V wiring needs some work.

Answer (score 2):

you are likely the victim of some variant of ground bounce.

Don't put motor current through a solderless breadboard.

connect both 12V input leads to the ULN board, then connect from the ULN board ground ground to the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your last question it's could already be dead. To make sure it's not, buy a new one or go through all the functions of the GPIO and processor and verify that they work.

One way to do this is to get a logic analyzer (the USB ones are cheap and less than 40$) you can toggle each pin an verify that the pin is toggling on the logic analyzer scope.

Also make sure you can upload code (and it verify that it works). Make a simple program to toggle an LED or something.

If something breaks you have to verify all the pieces are working.

Comment: The last one cannot upload, and additionally several have meet horrible deaths due to this circuit. I'm wondering why this circuit seems to be such a killer

Comment: It's probably the LED on the ground, that can cause problems. I'd get a new arudino. Make sure that when you connect GPIO's that you don't exceed the current limit on GPIO's

Comment: Yes this current limit was my concern for the others, how can I ensure that I do not exceed it?

Comment: Make sure you don't connect a digital output to an output and drive them in opposite directions (one port 0, one port 1). Don't connect a digital input or output to anything higher than Vcc. Use current limiting resistors. There are other ways to blow out ports, I can't list them all. Don't drive an output into ground if it's high.